# I am using discord.py and am trying to get the author name but it is giving me the client ID instead

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

`embed.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.mention)`
This line of code works but I want it to give the actual name of the person not the ID. Even though the tagging part doesn't work either, I can solve that later but if anyone would be willing to let me know how to tag in the title or author of an embed, that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you use discord.py rewrite since it's more popular than the original (I think)

There are a couple of ways of doing this, depending on if you want the discriminator (the #XXXX part after each username) or just the username itself.

### **Without the discriminator**

You can use the `User.display_name` or `User.name` property, for example:

```
embed.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.display_name)
```

This will return the username **without** the discriminator, docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=display_name#discord.abc.User.display_name). 
Using User.display_name will also take into account if the user has a nickname or not, however using User.name will return the users discord username, without the nickname.

### **With the discriminator**

If you do want the discriminator at the end of the username, you can use `str(user)`:

```
embed.set_author(name=str(ctx.message.author))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this line of code:

for name:

```
username = ctx.message.author.name
```

for display name:

```
username = ctx.message.author.display_name
```